# CWD C++ Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to have my program change directory (to where the user wishes to) but I am unable to navigate there and create a file? It appears that I am able to navigate there but when I get to the next system call it returns back to the current directory

Is there a way to set where my program cwd is pointing to?

```
std::string s1 = "cd " + userDirectory;
system(s1.c_str());
system("dir > test.txt");
```

Comment: It's not that `cd` fails, but the problem is that it changes the current working directory for that `system` call, _and only that call_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [SetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx) Win32 on Windows.
- [chdir()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chdir.html) / [_chdir](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1.aspx) for POSIX (a common C API available on many OS:es).
- [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)/[std::filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) `current_path()` for C++ (std in C++17).

Comment: chdir is not a part of C standard library (POSIX maybe?) and should not be used on Windows.

Comment: @VTT: Added _chdir for windows C api. POSIX it is.

Answer (score 2):

The [`system`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) function starts a new command interpreter as a new process. And then runs the commands in that command interpreter. And as the `cd` command is a built-in command it will only apply to that command interpreter process, not your process.

You have a couple of solutions you can try:

- Put the commands (`cd` and `dir` and everything else) in to a script file that you run.
- Change the working directory of *your* process.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can change working directory using `SetCurrentDirectoryW` function.